# gatsby, redux, Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(CartContainer)"

Tags: reactjs, redux, gatsby

The code was working fine in react-redux v5 but when I upgraded to v7 I obtained the following runtime error when navigating to the page with the CartContainer:

```
react-dom.development.js:11102 Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in the context of 
"Connect(CartContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom 
React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer 
to Connect(CartContainer) in connect options.
```

Now I do wrap the root-level component in a Provider, in the typical gatsby way,
Here is the ReduxWrapper.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllProducts } from './src/actions'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './src/reducers';

const middleware = [ thunk ];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  middleware.push(createLogger());
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(...middleware))
store.dispatch(getAllProducts())

export default ({ element }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>{element}</Provider>
);
```

The store instance should run downstream into any container that has connect() called on it.
additionally both gatsby-Browser.js and gatsby-ssr.js have the following:

```
export { default as wrapRootElement } from './ReduxWrapper';
```

the connected component in question, CartContainer.js is given below:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { checkout } from '../actions'
import { getTotal, getCartProducts } from '../reducers'
import Cart from '../components/checkout/Cart'

const CartContainer = ({ products, total, checkout }) => (
  <Cart
    products={products}
    total={total}
    onCheckoutClicked={() => checkout(products)} />
)

CartContainer.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    quantity: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  })).isRequired,
  total: PropTypes.string,
  checkout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: getCartProducts(state),
  total: getTotal(state)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { checkout }
)(CartContainer)
```

I am expecting CartContainer to have access to the store, and I suspect the problem lies with the fact I upgraded react-redux from v5 to v7, Since everything was working fine until that moment.
My dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "David W",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.19.45",
    "gatsby-background-image": "^0.10.2",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.43",
    "gatsby-plugin-env-variables": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.39",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.32",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.23",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.29",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.4.3",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.46",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.13",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.6",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.7.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.2.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.19.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,json,md}\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "gatsby build",
    "start": "gatsby serve",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default#readme",
  "main": "gatsby-browser.js"
}
```

Comment: You export wrapRootElement like `export { default as wrapRootElement } from './ReduxWrapper';` but shouldn't you filename be `GatsbyWrapper` as mentioned in your post. So the solution should be `export { default as wrapRootElement } from './GatsbyWrapper';`

Comment: @Shubham Khatri just changed filename in SO question, the program already had ReduxWrapper.js so no change to program.